# Django error in django-social-auth

Tags: python, django, facebook, authentication, oauth

I am newbie in Django. I am implementing the facebook authentication in my app. The Error that i am getting in my terminal output is like ;

```
File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 324, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social_auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.utils.importlib import import_module
ImportError: No module named importlib
```

What i am doing wrong? IS my newly installed django-python-social installed correctly?

Comment: Seems like your django installation is broken. `django.utils.importlib import import_module ImportError: No module named importlib`

Comment: Any idea how should i fix this?

Comment: Try reinstalling django. Which version of django are you using? Importlib was deprecated and was to be removed in django 1.9

Comment: I am using django 1.9

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like **django-social-auth** have already [issues](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/issues/833) with django 1.8, so I don't wonder if it has problems with django 1.9. I will recommand to use [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) since it's the most [used/rated package](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/social/) for social network, and it's easy to configure:

1. `pip install django-allauth`
2. **settings.py** config

   ```
   TEMPLATES = [
   {
       'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
       'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
       'APP_DIRS': True,
       'OPTIONS': {
           'context_processors': [
               ....
               "django.core.context_processors.request",
               # allauth specific context processors
               "allauth.account.context_processors.account",
               "allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount",
           ],
       },
   },]

   AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
       # Default backend 
       "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
       # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
       "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
   )

   INSTALLED_APPS += (
       # The Django sites framework is required
       'django.contrib.sites',
       'allauth',
       'allauth.account',
       'allauth.socialaccount',
        # Login Facebook provider
        'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
   )
   SITE_ID = 1
   ```
3. in **urls.py**  add:

   ```
   urlpatterns = patterns('',
       ...
       #Auth URLS
       url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
   )
   ```
4. Finally apply database migration
5. run server and go to the admin interface at
   http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/sites/site and create a Site for
   the localhost, 127.0.0.1:8000, or your website domain for
   production. It should have an id equal to the SITE_ID configured
   before in the setting.
6. Configure your facebook app to get secret key, and then create a Social Application for Facebook at http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/socialaccount/socialapp

--> you may also find this [tutoriel](http://www.techstricks.com/django-allauth-tutorial-step-by-step/) useful

Answer (score 6):

django-social-auth has officially been deprecated in favour of python-social-auth. So you should not be using it. Moreover the import error is most probably due to incompatibility with Django 1.9 as importlib has been deprecated from django.

Comment: OKay Should i Use django 1.8 for the development purpose?

Comment: No. Use python-social-auth instead