# Trying to use django-allauth but I keep getting " ImportError: No module named 'allauth.account' "?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-allauth

I am following the steps provided here:

[Django error in django-social-auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253642/django-error-in-django-social-auth)

And also here:

http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

And the same error comes from using both methods. What am I doing wrong?
I am using a virtual environment if that affects anything. The exact thing I am getting is this:
EDIT: Also had this top part:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:\Users\Bararon\Envs\cinemaphile\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 118, in create
>       cls = getattr(mod, cls_name)
>
> AttributeError: module 'allauth' has no attribute 'account'
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "manage.py", line 10, in 
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>
> File "C:\Users\Bararon\Envs\cinemaphile\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()
>
> File "C:\Users\Bararon\Envs\cinemaphile\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 327, in execute
>       django.setup()
>
> File "C:\Users\Bararon\Envs\cinemaphile\lib\site-packages\django__init__.py", >line 18, in setup
>       apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
>
> File "C:\Users\Bararon\Envs\cinemaphile\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
>       app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
>
> File "C:\Users\Bararon\Envs\cinemaphile\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 123, in create
>       import_module(entry)
>
> File "C:\Users\Bararon\Envs\cinemaphile\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>
> File "", line 986, in _gcd_import
>
> File "", line 969, in _find_and_load
>
> File "", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> ImportError: No module named 'allauth.account'

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # My Apps
    'base',
    'users', 

    # The Django sites framework is required
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
     # Login Facebook provider
     'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',

    ]
```

Comment: is this when you run ./manage.py migrate? Please do a pip3 freeze | grep allauth and let us know if django allauth shows up in it

Comment: django-allauth==0.25.2 shows up from pip3 freeze. And yes, it shows up when I do migrate.

Comment: can you post your installed_apps part of the settigns

Comment: Will be edited in.

Comment: do you by any chance have a file named allauth.py or account.py ?

Comment: No I don't. Have already check if everything is up to date and used the shell to check if I could import allauth. I could, after removing anything associated with allauth from settings.py

Comment: clean out your INSTALLED_APPS so that it's the same as what was created by startproject and then add the apps one at a time. Start with allauth. Add your things last. Try migrate (but take care not to drop any tables (hit no if asked))

Comment: I did it for all the apps and every single one of them worked except allauth.account

Comment: I just checked the directory and account isn't even there!

Comment: Seems like a corrupt install then. uninstall and install again. If worse comes to worse, you can actually put the allauth directory into your project and it will work (but obviously this is not ideal)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think I'm gonna make a fresh virtual environment for it.

Comment: At the end of settings.py do a pprint(os.paths) and see if the location of your module is listed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where I was getting an error like
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth.socialaccountcore'

And all I did to fix it was change the order of installed apps list in settings.py.
Old order:

```
NSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.sites',
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
'core'
```

]

New order:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.sites',
'core',
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
```

]
I could not really understand it well why would it happen.
May be some one who understands can help with explanation.